# lightgallery typeError images not loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bootstrap page and I downloaded jquery plugin (lightgallery.js) and plugins works very well with theese codes;

```
    <div class="item active" id="lightgallery">
     <a href="http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg">
      <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg" alt="...">
     </a>
      <a href="http://s.fotorama.io/2.jpg">
         <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/2.jpg" alt="...">
       </a>
    </div>
```

and this is my jquery function to work plugin

```
 $('#lightgallery').lightGallery();
```

it's good but if I change my html structure plugin is not work

my html structure is below;

```
<div id="lightgallery">

  <div class="item active">
    <a href="http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg">
       <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg" alt="...">
    </a>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <a href="http://s.fotorama.io/2.jpg">
         <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/2.jpg" alt="...">
       </a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the full error from the console?

Comment: hi @Uzbekjon I solved problem using selector thank a lot it work's well but javascript error notifier gave this error; Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Answer (score 1):

Use a list like this..

```
<ul id="lightgallery">
    <li class="item active">
        <a href="http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg">
            <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="http://s.fotorama.io/2.jpg">
            <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/2.jpg">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The plugin readme suggests that the plugin [does not force any markup](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery#the-markup). Have you encountered this problem earlier? Could you elaborate why this would help?

Comment: hi I solved problem using selector thank a lot it work's well but javascript error notifier gave this error;
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ...

Comment: This is the structure they used in the source for their own website.